# Первые элементы списка списков list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список списков:

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
[0.4, 0.5, 0.6,],
[0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]
```

Как я могу получить каждый первый элемент из каждого списка, потом каждый второй и тд. и записать все в список списков:

```
[[0.1, 0.4, 0.7],
[0.2, 0.5, 0.8],
[0.3, 0.6, 0,9]]
```

Comment: первый элемент списка - ``lst[0]``, второй элмент списка - ``lst[1]`` и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Эта операция называется "транспонирование матрицы" *(поворот матрицы относительно своей главной диагонали)*. В Питоне это делается в одну строчку:

```
m = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
     [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
     [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]

t = list(map(list, zip(*m)))
```

```
[[0.1, 0.4, 0.7],
 [0.2, 0.5, 0.8],
 [0.3, 0.6, 0.9]]
```

Если вместо списка списков сойдёт и список кортежей, то вызов `map()` можно выкинуть.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня только получился список, а не список списков почему-то

Comment: @Anna Скопируйте мой код да проверьте - получится список списков.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
start_list = [
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
[0.4, 0.5, 0.6,],
[0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
]

new_list = []

lst = []

for i in range(len(start_list)):
    for c in start_list:
        lst.append(c[i])
    new_list.append(lst)
    lst = []
print(new_list)
```

Понимаю, что можно сделать гораздо короче, но этот код для тех, кто обладает начальными знаниями языка.